# Redirecting paths to shebang through .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had a small bit of code that would redirect pages accessed from my own domain to their hash addresses, like so:

```
example.com/stationary.html => example.com/#/stationary
```

This was the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # Redirect requests to ajax pages the their hashes
 RewriteCond $1 !=index [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html?$ /#$1 [NE,R]
</IfModule>
```

This would work great, now I'm wondering can I get it to redirect pages like

```
example.com/stationary => example.com/#!/stationary
```

Hacking the above code didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: .htaccess questions aren't allowed on stackoverflow anymore? Then why do we have related tags, puzzled.

Comment: I have no idea what casperOne was thinking.  It seems to be a perfectly cromulent question to me.

Comment: .htaccess questions go on ServerFault.  They are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @casperOne: .htaccess questions are on-topic for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think a "hash address" is; a URL with a hash mark in it refers to an anchor *on the page in question,* and is not a resource in and of itself.

Refer to RFC 2616 for details.

Regardless, as to your question: you will have to repeat the entire Rule, including all RewriteConds, to match something else.

```
RewriteCond $1 ! \.html?$ [NC]
...
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /#!/$1 [NE,R]
```

Also, move the "**-**" to the end of the collection so you don't have to escape it.

Oh, and get rid of the IfModule; you would *know* if it's loaded or not.